# Find the limit?

Tags: limits

How to calculate this limit ?

$$\lim _{x\to 1}\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{\sqrt[3]{x-1}}$$

[An image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJ0z8.png) for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can rewrite the function:
$$\frac{\sqrt{x^{2}-1}}{\sqrt[3]{x-1}}=(x+1)^{\frac{1}{2}}(x-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}(x-1)^{-\frac{1}{3}}=(x+1)^{\frac{1}{2}}(x-1)^{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}}$$
So that

$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\sqrt{x^{2}-1}}{\sqrt[3]{x-1}}=\lim_{x\to 1}(x+1)^{\frac{1}{2}}(x-1)^{\frac{1}{6}}=0$$

Comment: I did the same thing but forgot $$(x+1)$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim _{ x\rightarrow 1 }{ \left( \frac { \sqrt { { x }^{ 2 }-1 }  }{ \sqrt [ 3 ]{ x-1 }  }  \right) = } \lim _{ x\rightarrow 1 }{ \left( \sqrt [ 6 ]{ \frac { { \left( { x }^{ 2 }-1 \right)  }^{ 3 } }{ { \left( x-1 \right)  }^{ 2 } }  }  \right) = } \lim _{ x\rightarrow 1 }{ \left( \sqrt [ 6 ]{ \frac { { \left( { x }-1 \right) ^{ 3 }\left( { x }+1 \right)  }^{ 3 } }{ { \left( x-1 \right)  }^{ 2 } }  }  \right) = } \lim _{ x\rightarrow 1 }{ \left( \sqrt [ 6 ]{ \left( { x }-1 \right) \left( { x }+1 \right) ^{ 3 } }  \right) =0 } $$